# Bind db.x configuration files

Tags: configuration, nameserver, bind

Where can I find good, informative tutorial about configuration files in *bind*?
I have these files (and other irrelevant ones):

```
db.0  db.10  db.127  db.255  db.empty  db.internal  db.local  db.root
```

I guess that db.10 works for IPs beginning with 10, and so on, but the internal structure of the file is quite unclear.

I have looked this up in Google and found very little reference to these files; Can anyone post a reference to a good source?

Thanks,

Udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Bind Zone Files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file).  DNS arranges data not by *domain*, but by *zone*; when it is presented to the client and processed, it is not by *zone*, but by *domain*.  There is a distinct difference.  You can read [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) and parts of [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) for more information.

[I would recommend the "Grasshopper" book for further reading](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575/).  It can be a bit dry at times, but the first 4 chapters are priceless and will expand your understanding of DNS in an appreciable way.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Could you please elaborate about the precedence of resolving?

Comment: +1 to second the "Grasshopper" recommendation - an excellent book.

Comment: @Udi, have a look at this answer (and the answers to that question in general)... http://serverfault.com/questions/2966/is-there-a-good-overview-of-the-dns-system/2985#2985